# C# - Forms Authentication Code-Behind w Custom Role and Membership Providers

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication, membership-provider, roleprovider

Unfortunately, all the examples for Forms Authentication Code Behind w/ Custom Role and Membership Providers I find online are written with a VB.NET code behind and I need a C# code behind. Please help!!!!

I need a codebehind that will do the following:

- authenticate user upon login button click
- if user active_flag=0 (false) OR password!=@password, display error: "Access Denied"
- if user admin_flag=1 & active flag=1 (true), redirect to admin_pages\zipsearch.aspx
- if user admin_flag=0 (false) & active_flag=1 (true), redirect to pages\zipsearch.aspx

Default.aspx Code:

```
    <asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" RenderOuterTable="false">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <span class="failureNotification">
            <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </span>
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="LoginUserValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification" 
             ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup"/>
        <div class="accountInfo">
            <fieldset class="login">
                <legend>Account Information</legend>
                <p>
                    <asp:Label ID="usernameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="username">Username:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="username" 
                         CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." 
                         ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <asp:Label ID="passwordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="password">Password:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="password"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="passwordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="password" 
                         CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." 
                         ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server"/>
                    <asp:Label ID="RememberMeLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RememberMe" CssClass="inline">Keep me logged in</asp:Label>
                </p>
            </fieldset>
            <p class="submitButton">
                <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup"/>
            </p>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```

Web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/default.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>

  <membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
      <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="OleConnectionStringSource"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />  
  </providers>
</membership> 

<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
   <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/> 
  </providers>
</profile>

<roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
      <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" /> 
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Default.aspx.cs code behind:

```
namespace ACAWebApplication
{
  public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
  { 
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Register.aspx?ReturnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);

       // authenticate user
       // if user active_flag=0 (false) OR password!=@password, display error: "Access Denied" 

       // if user admin_flag=1 & active flag=1 (true), redirect to admin_pages\zipsearch.aspx
       // if user admin_flag=0 (false) & active_flag=1 (true), redirect to pages\zipsearch.aspx

      }
   }
 }
```

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

to make a start here you go with the login method:

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // Validate the user against the Membership framework user store
 if (Membership.ValidateUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text))
 {
 // Log the user into the site
 FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserName.Text, RememberMe.Checked);
 }
 // If we reach here, the user's credentials were invalid
 InvalidCredentialsMessage.Visible = true;
}
```

you can check the user credentials within the authenticate method:

```
protected void myLogin_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
 // Get the email address entered
 TextBox EmailTextBox = myLogin.FindControl("Email") as TextBox;
 string email = EmailTextBox.Text.Trim();

 // Verify that the username/password pair is valid
 if (Membership.ValidateUser(myLogin.UserName, myLogin.Password))
 {
 // Username/password are valid, check email
 MembershipUser usrInfo = Membership.GetUser(myLogin.UserName);
 if (usrInfo != null && string.Compare(usrInfo.Email, email, true) == 0)
 {
 // Email matches, the credentials are valid
 e.Authenticated = true;
 }
 else
 {
 // Email address is invalid...
 e.Authenticated = false;
 }
 }
 else
 {
 // Username/password are not valid...
 e.Authenticated = false;
 }
}
```

For redirection depending on a specific role use this code:

```
protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "Admin"))
    {
         Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Default.aspx");
    }
    else if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "User"))
    {
         Response.Redirect("~/User/Default.aspx");
    }
    else if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "Viewer"))
    {
         Response.Redirect("~/Viewer/Default.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
         Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Here is the solution which should work for you not the best code but still ok.

So first of all you make configure your login control with the DestinationPageUrl tag like this:

```
<asp:Login 
  ID="Login1" 
  runat="server" 
  DestinationPageUrl="~/admin_pages/zipsearch.aspx">
</asp:Login>
```

Then in your LoginButton_Click method:

```
 protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     // Validate the user against the Membership framework user store
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(myLogin.UserName, myLogin.Password))
     {
     // Username/password are valid, check email
     MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser(myLogin.UserName);

        if (currentUser != null)
        {
            if (admin_flag == true)
              {
                     FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserName.Text, RememberMe.Checked);
            }
           else
              {
              // If we reach here, the user's credentials were invalid -> your access is denied message
             InvalidCredentialsMessage.Visible = true;
            }
        }
      }
      //if code goes here validation of user failed        
    }
```

Comment: @Mugan, Thanks for the response! Where do i put the redirect URL and the admin_flag and active_flag check? Under if (Membership.ValidateUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text))? Why does RedirectFromLoginPage pass the UserName.Text and RememberMe.Checked values but not tell it what page to redirect to?

Comment: the url is a property called "DestinationPageUrl" of your login control therefore you don't have to set it here. Yes you can put your code before the redirection.

Comment: @Mug4n, thanks for your response! Where can the Roles.IsUserInRole values be set and stored for each user in the database? I currently have an admin_flag boolean column under the App_User table in the database with a value of 1 or 0 for each user.

Comment: @Mug4n, the RedirectPage can be set under Web.config under <configuration> <appSettings><add key="RedirectPage" value="/Pages/default.aspx"/> right?

Comment: take a look at your membership database. (you can also create your own membership database see here: http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-vb) There you will find a table with the name aspnet_roles. Within this table you can define different roles. There is also a built in tool in visual studio to maintain your membership database see here: http://odetocode.com/articles/427.aspx

Comment: @Mug4n, thanks for the links! Can't this be setup so Admin users can set the roles for themselves and their subordinate users off an Admin page so I don't have to constantly maintain the database? Wouldn't it be easier to forgo the Role Providers and say: if User's Admin_flag=0, redirect to admin/default.aspx ?

Comment: well you can do whatever you want the membership database is free to adapt your needs. The Admin can create users and roles by code to with the Membership and MembershipUser and Roles classes. Of course you can make your if clause like you mention it above that is fine too.

Comment: normally you create your roles manually within the roles table and then you can create the users with the createuserwizard which creates the new users and gives them a role...

Comment: @Mug4n, thanks for the response. How would I code it to just look for the admin_flag and scrap the roles? haha